# Two errors I get in JSLint for no good reason

Tags: javascript, jslint

I checked the following code in [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Reset textarea</title>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea id="ta">
        <p>Hello</p>
    </textarea>
    <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="reset();">
    <script>
        function reset() {
            var ta = document.getElementById('ta');
            if (!ta.value || ta.value != ta.defaultValue && confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                ta.value = ta.defaultValue;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Mori/e2Fzm/)**

And I got the following errors:

> Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='.

Since the textarea value and default value are always of the type `string`, then there's no type conversion before comparison and it makes absolutely no difference except making your JS file larger!

> The '&&' subexpression should be wrapped in parens.

Why should I add parentheses when `&&` has a higher [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) than `||`? I can simply remove [nested parentheses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Removing_nested_parentheses) instead of:

```
if (!ta.value || (ta.value != ta.defaultValue && confirm('Are you sure?')))
```

Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: jslint will always prefer a strict comparison no matter what. Additionally, the latter comes up because of short-circuiting. It's just a way to guarantee you get the results you expect to get.

Comment: JSLint is somebodies interpretation of best-practice, although lots of experience has gone into defining the rules it's subjective and will not necessarily line up with your idea of what constitutes best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSLint is designed to produce more human-readable code, using the rules defined by whoever wrote JSLint (which may be based on other peoples' opinion, but ultimately is just opinion)

Therefore, `!==` is more human-readable than `!=` because it makes it obvious that the comparison is strict. However, you know different because `ta.value` and `ta.defaultValue` are indeed always strings, so you aren't required to follow JSLint's advice.

Similarly, parenthesising the `&&` expression makes it more human-readable, because it makes it clear what order things are run in. While you may know order of precedence, not everyone does at a glance and may interpret it wrong.

To restate, JSLint is advice and opinion, not law.

Comment: Thanks for the sensible _and_ quick reply! It was like you were answering my question while I was typing it! :)

Comment: I have secretly hacked StackOverflow to publish questions as they are typed and make them visible to me.